# Unable to instantiate activity Component Info Class Not found exception Android

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

My app is deployed directly to any device without any exception. But when .apk is installed it throws the following exception. Secondly it runs fine with Nougat 7.0 and above versions but crashes with same exception for lower OS Versions like 5.0 and 6.0. etc.  What is the reason for exception ?

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Build.gradle:**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'm-zaes'
            keyPassword 'm-zaes'
            storeFile file('D:/AMI_Repo/AMI_Designer/Targets/Android/AMI 3d Player v3/keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'm-zaes'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile 'D:/AMI_Repo/AMI_Designer/Targets/Android/AMI 3d Player v3/app/proguard-android.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
        compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev180-1.22.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        //glide
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

        // CardView
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

and **Stack trace** is

```
Process: amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3, PID: 15548
                                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3/amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2564)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:170)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1441)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1070)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2564) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:170) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1441) 
                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750) 
                                                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles
                                                                                                           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                                ... 13 more
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

and **Folder Structure:**[image]

Comment: can you show your manifest ?

Comment: see updated question @AnchalSingh

Comment: Class not found exception comes when you have created a class but you didn;t provided it in manifest. So, which class you want to load ?

Comment: show me full code of your build.gradle file.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar Please see updated question

Comment: what is the parent class of LoaderOfAllMediaFiles?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar Activity

Comment: change it to AppCompatActivity  first, if you are developing app for above 21 API always use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity, and explain me one more thing,  your base package is amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3 and your activity package is amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles any specific reason about it?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar I've changed it to AppCompatActivity for more info see my Updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146655/discussion-between-aniruddh-parihar-and-ami-amitekh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As Discussion in chat i found that, Your manual way of generating APK
>   is not  generating the correct APK, so i am Suggesting these way to
>   generating APK for Manual Install:

**For Debug Build**

- Delete you build folder inside the App folder.
- Goto `Build>Build APk`. it will generate .apk file in your
  `app>build>output>apk` directory.
- COPY it your device and install manually.

**For Release Build**

- Delete you build folder inside the App folder.
- Goto `Build>Generate Signed APk` and provide recomended Details, make sure your `Build type : release` and have checked both signature version `v1(jar signature)` and `v2(full apk signature)` . it will generate .apk file in your
  `app>build>output>apk` directory.
- COPY it your device and install manually.

Answer (score 2):

At first "Clean" and "Sync Project with Gradle Files". Then run your code

Comment: use in manifest :<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"                                                                                    android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
<activity
        android:name="amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles"         
</activity>
```

with this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".amitechnologies.products.apps.equalizeraudioplayer.v3.view.LoaderOfAllMediaFiles"         
 </activity>
```

The reason is you have missed a  dot(.) in android:name

Answer (score 0):

If your minSDK version less than 21 you need to do the following for multidex

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your_app_package">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your Build folder inside the app folder and rebuild your project