# Not able to install release apk for product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have generated my signed apk for product flavors, but when i try to install the apk in my device, it says "App not installed"

Here is my gradle file code :-

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.olivesync"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

productFlavors{

    main {
        applicationId "com.app.olivesync"
    }

     resonance {
         applicationId "com.app.resonance"
     }

}
dependencies {
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
}
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
}
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
}

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.github.iammert:MaterialIntroView:1.6.0'}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: follow this post....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543270/unable-to-instantiate-activity-component-info-class-not-found-exception-android/44545253#44545253

if this will not resolve then let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: What error is returned by `adb` when you install app?

Comment: Do you have the app on the device (with the same applicationId)?. If so try removing it first. When installing an app with same applicationId but different certificate this error may rise.

Comment: Done. Actually i was building for debug one. So changing the build variants to release one solved the issue.Thank you everyone for helping :-) .

Answer (score 0):

change your version and then try to build sign apk. Hope it will work.